# Using existing Database Sequence and creating custom generator

Tags: oracle, hibernate, oracle11g, sequence

I have created a sequence in my Database as follows:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "SCOTT"."ATA_SEQ_USERID" 
MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 
INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1000 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE ;
```

Now, I want to append the first two letters of the name of the user to the number created by this sequence and generate a user id everytime a new user registers, using Hibernate. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the way to do it.

```
String sql = "select MY_SEQ_ID.nextval from dual";
        SQLQuery query = session.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
        List idList=query.list();
        BigDecimal number=(BigDecimal) idList.get(0);
        System.out.println(number);
```

where MY_SEQ_ID is my sequence id.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use:

- **SUBSTR** function
- **concatenation operator** `||` .

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE s;

Sequence created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT substr(ename, 1, 2)||s.nextval custom_seq FROM emp;

CUSTOM_SEQ
------------------------------------------
SM1
AL2
WA3
JO4
MA5
BL6
CL7
SC8
KI9
TU10
AD11
JA12
FO13
MI14

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: I need to use this sequence in my web project and then generate the id, using HQL.

Comment: @AbhineetKumar Ah! ok. I added the hibernate tag back to your question. I am sorry, I could only help with the SQL query part. Can you use the query output in the application?

Comment: Well, if I can know the equivalent HQL statement for the query that you have given, I think it can work.

Comment: @AbhineetKumar That's cool! Please mark it answered if it helped you. Would help others.

Comment: No, it didn't. I couldn't get the result from the database into an iterator or a  list after executing the above query. It says that Iterator is not supported in native SQL Queries.

Comment: Ok, may be something to be researched about application code side.